# Text not displaying proper in chrome but works in FF?

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

Please check the image 
[image]

In chrome [bit.ly/10bYbyi](http://bit.ly/10bYbyi)
You can see in FF [bit.ly/10bYbyi](http://bit.ly/10bYbyi) its work proper.

I want to fix this via css, but when i open debug tool and close it without doing any change the text will appear proper.

Why this happening ? What should I do to get text slider proper in chrome as in FF.

Comment: Have you validated your HTML and set a doc type? Which piece of text? What's the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try this:

We need to set **max-width** property for solve Chrome issue.

Use following CSS.

```
.nivo-caption {
   max-width: 600px!important;
   min-width: auto!important;
   display: block!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you can see i have added this css but still its not solving chrome issue.

Answer (score 2):

Set min-width with !important css flag-

```
.nivo-caption{
   min-width:600px!important;
}
```